# pl sql column name as parameter

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, sql-order-by, dynamic-sql

this is the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE select_vehicles(IN name_of_column VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM vehicle order by name_of_column;
END
$$ DELIMITER ;
```

The code has no errors, but the "order by " is not working.

how can i pass column names as a parameter and work with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need dynamic SQL to pass a column name as a paramater. So something like:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE select_vehicles(IN name_of_column VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM vehicle order by `', name_of_column, '`');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
$$
```

Comment: Thanks !
I was trying with the (SET CONCAT EXECUTE ) but i didnt know the PREPARE

Comment: Also recommend to put the column name in back-ticks in case it is a reserved keyword.

Comment: @BillKarwin: yes, that's a good point, I edited my answer to include that. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks bill his was also useful forsomething like this:

DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE PROCEDURE select_vehicles(IN name_of_column VARCHAR(255),IN is_desc_sorting BOOLEAN ) 
BEGIN 
SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM vehicle order by `', name_of_column,'`'); 
IF is_desc_sorting THEN SET @sql = CONCAT(@sql,' DESC'); 
END IF; PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt; 
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;